# How do I name the sheets in an Excel export

Tags: list-manipulation, export, excel

I have a three level nested list. When I export the list as an Excel document, I get the data in three different Excel sheets, as I require. I would like to know how to change the name of the Excel sheets from within Mathematica. As an example how do I name the following sheets when exporting the list

```
table = Table[a b c, {a, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}, {c, 1, 3}];
Export["test.xls", table, "XLS"];
```

as "a=1", "a=2" and "a=3" as shown in the picture below?

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Export["test.xls", "newname" -> table, "XLS"];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible implementation can be:

```
table = Table[a b c, {a, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}, {c, 1, 3}];
names = "a=" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[Length@table]
t4 = MapThread[Rule, {names, table}]


Export["C:/test4.xls", t4, "XLS"];
```